# Fubini's Theorem, but $dxdy = -dydx$

Tags: integration, differential-forms

As differential $2$-forms, clearly $dxdy=-dydx$ by alternation. Yet just as clearly, $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 dxdy \neq -\int_0^1 \int_0^1 dydx$. Where's the abuse of notation here?

Comment: You've written the same on both sides of the second equation. And you haven't explained where and why you see a problem.

Comment: Sorry, fat fingers.

Comment: You need to match up the orientation when integrating differential forms by definition, to avoid exactly this problem.

Comment: Check carefully how the integral of a $2$-form over an *oriented* $2$-dimensional manifold is defined. In particular, how is the integral of $f\,dx\wedge dy$ over a region in $\Bbb R^2$ (with the *usual* orientation) defined?

Answer (score 4):

$(x,y)\mapsto(y,x)$ is an orientation-reversing map of the plane to itself.
For orientation-reversing maps one has to introduce a minus sign factor in the
change of variables:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\,dx\wedge\,dy=-\int_0^1\int_0^1-\,dy\wedge\,dx
=\int_0^1\int_0^1\,dy\wedge\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon Lord Shark's answer: remember that when changing coordinate systems, you need to introduce the determinant of the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation. In your case, the Jacobian is

$$
J(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial x} \\
   \frac{\partial y}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \, ,
$$
whose determinant is $-1$. Therefore,
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 dx \wedge dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \det(J(x,y)) \, (-dy \wedge dx) = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 dy \wedge dx
$$

As Lord Shark pointed out, any orientation-reversing transformation will have a Jacobian whose determinant is $-1$.